# Is there a way to add a featured image to an image/file attachment page?

Tags: images, pages, facebook, pdf

So what I'm wanting to do is be able to use the url of an attachment page for a PDF file, post that link on Facebook, and be able to customize the preview/featured image that shows up there.

I've tried adding facebook og image code to the Description section when I go in to edit the attachment file in the wordpress backend, but I can't seem to get that to work.

Is there a way to accomplish this or am I out of luck?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you generating the og:image meta tags for the rest of your site - manually, or with a plugin? I suspect your plugin would work if you could put the right postmeta data on the attachment post record, but it'd depend on your plugin's UI for it.

Comment: That's assuming your attachment page shows an HTML page, i.e. you have an appropriate attachment template in your theme or the regular post template just works OK. You could always make a simple post with the PDF instead of the attachment page and set up the og:image on that page as usual.